# Today, can one buy stocks in a stock exchange market without being a registered member of that market?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, broker

Stock exchange markets are not my expertise and I don't know all the markets in the world (let along the history of generally any one of these markets), but all those I know do require registered membership (often with certain terms and costs).

Can one buy stocks in a stock exchange market without being a registered member of that market?
For example, since about year 2000, more and more stock exchange software have been created; many [Free Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) products are often [gratis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre) and *pro-anonymity* so at least in the software context some stock exchange markets might allow trading without registry.

Comment: Questions of personal finance/investing do not belong on economics.se. Please have a look at our help center and avoid posting question that are considered off topic.  I am moving this to personal finance and money stack, you should still check their help center and make any edits/changes according to their rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are stocks traded via stock brokers?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12314/why-are-stocks-traded-via-stock-brokers)

Comment: Related: [What is needed to be a "broker"?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/86057/what-is-needed-to-be-a-broker)

Comment: Are you asking about brokers? Most people who buy shares aren’t members of any stock exchange.

Comment: There is a difference between software and people. There might even be free stock exchange software, that you can run on your own computer, and make your own stock exchange. But other people (who own stocks you want to buy) aren't using *your* stock exchange, they're using NASDAQ or NYSE or London SE or Frankfurter Wertpapierbörse. So running the software is no use to you.

Comment: @ummarredinquirer, can you cite some of the software packages you referred to? There are certainly packages that (theoretically) help you manage and track your portfolio; I use a personal finance program that downloads current prices and my current holdings on request and does some extremely basic analysis... But that's very different from trying to avoid using a brokerage. For my mutual funds I use the "house" broker system set up by the company running the funds rather than having another broker, but that's strictly for those funds. What are you actually trying to accomplish?